# CSS not being applied in springboot templates html Files

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have confirmed that my thymeleaf is working as i tested with a th:if.
and if i open the html file on my browser with the backup link it works.

[This is my workplace line 6 and i am kinda sure its correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L64jj.png)

Answer (score 0):

use link
"link relation="stylesheet" Hypertext Reference="style.css"></link"
I use full form cuz my answer were not got submitted with short one